# Making a copy of/a pointer to a typedef struct

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I have a structure filled with some data and would like to make a copy of it by assigning a pointer to it.

I have the following structure:

```
typedef struct items {
    double cijena;
    char sifra[100], naziv[100];
}   ITEM, *ITEMcopy;
```

`*ITEMcopy` is supposed to be a pointer to the contents of ITEM (a copy).

In `int main()`:

```
ITEM items[n];
ITEM *ITEMcopy = &items; // this is wrong
```

`*ITEMcopy` is supposed to be used in a function that I later want to edit the contents of:

```
void sort(ITEM **items, int n)
```

So basically, instead of directly editing `ITEM items[n]` contents, I want to assign a pointer to the data it holds and edit that instead.

Part of the code that produces the error is `ITEM *ITEMcopy = &items;`

---

`warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type`

I hope I was somewhat clear.

Comment: `ITEM *ITEMcopy = &items;` -> `ITEM *ITEMcopy = items;` or `ITEM *ITEMcopy = &items[0];`

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  Do you understand that setting a pointer to point to an object *does not* create a copy of the object?  It merely creates another way to access that object -- an "alias", as some would put it.

Comment: Also, do you understand that an array of objects of some type actually contains such objects themselves, not pointers to them?

Comment: Incompatible pointer type is because "&items" is of type "ITEM **". The '&' effectively adds another asterisk.

Comment: Assigning a pointer will not copy the data, it only provides an alternate "handle" for accessing the same data. Both items and ITEMcopy point to the same data, so if you alter the data that ITEMcopy points to, it will also change the data that items points to, because it is the same data.

Comment: Your post is so confused about whether you want to make a copy (*would like to make a copy of it by assigning a pointer to it*) or not make a copy ("instead of directly editing ITEM items[n] contents, I want to assign a pointer to the data it holds and edit that instead") that it's hard to know what you actually want. Can you please explain what you're really trying to do? Also, what specifically is your question?

Answer (score 1):

When you write:

```
ITEM items[n];
```

your are creating an array of `ITEM`s of length `n`, all the memory for the data is allocated on the stack. When you use the variable `items` it now refers to the first element in the array `items[0]` it is similar to a pointer but there is some extra info about it's length.

When you write:

```
ITEM *ITEMcopy;
```

you are creating a pointer called `ITEMcopy` that can contain the location of an `ITEM` but there is no memory allocated for any `ITEM`, `ITEMcopy` is just used to point to an already existing `ITEM`

If you assign it:

```
ITEM *ITEMcopy = items;
```

`ITEMcopy` points to the location of the first `ITEM` in `items`. So `ITEMcopy` is now a pointer to the first element in `items`.

When you write:

```
ITEM *ITEMcopy = &items;
```

This is giving you the warning because `items` already acts like a pointer. So `&items` is a pointer to a pointer to an `ITEM` which is not compatible with `ITEMcopy` which expects a pointer to an `ITEM`

The `sort` function should look something like this:

```
void sort(ITEM *items, int n)
```

To use the sort function:

```
ITEM items[n];
sort(items, n);
```

Using the variable in the function:

```
void sort(ITEM *items, int n)
{
    // could swap items[0] and items[1] like this
    ITEM itemBuf;
    memcpy(&itemBuf, &items[0], sizeof(ITEM));
    memcpy(&items[0], &items[1], sizeof(ITEM));
    memcpy(&items[1], &itemBuf, sizeof(ITEM));
}
```